# FBSDKProfile category frequently fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, runtime, facebook-sdk-4.0

I wrote a category for `FBSDKProfile` provided by the Facebook SDK V4 for iOS. This category enables me to fetch the user profile image and access it using the `[FBSDKProfile currentProfile]` singleton instance.

This is my category header file:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char const * const kProfileImageKey = "profile_image";

@interface FBSDKProfile (ProfileImage)

+(void)fetchProfileImageWithBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))handler;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *profileImage;

@end
```

And here's the implementation file:

```
#import "FBSDKProfile+ProfileImage.h"

@implementation FBSDKProfile (ProfileImage)

+(void)fetchProfileImageWithBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))handler {
    FBSDKProfile *currentProfile = [FBSDKProfile currentProfile];
    NSString *userId = currentProfile.userID;
    if (![userId isEqualToString:@""] && userId != Nil)
    {
        [self downloadFacebookProfileImageWithId:userId completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *profileImage) {
            currentProfile.profileImage = profileImage;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FBSDKProfileDidFetchProfileImageNotification object:nil];
            if (handler) { handler(succeeded); }
        }];
    } else
    {
        /* no user id */
        if (handler) { handler(NO); }
    }
}

+(void)downloadFacebookProfileImageWithId:(NSString *)profileId completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *profileImage))completionBlock
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", profileId]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if (!error)
                               {
                                   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   completionBlock(YES, image);
                               } else{
                                   completionBlock(NO, nil);
                               }
                           }];
}

#pragma mark - custom getter/setter methods

-(void)setProfileImage:(UIImage *)profileImage {
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kProfileImageKey, profileImage, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

-(UIImage *)profileImage {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kProfileImageKey);
}

@end
```

**The problem**

This solution works just the way it should most of the time, but it does, however, frequently fail. From what I can tell, I think it has to do with the storage of the image.

Upon the exception, if I do `po [FBSDKProfile currentProfile].profileImage`, it returns:

- error: property 'profileImage' not found on object of type 'FBSDKProfile *'
- error: 1 errors parsing expression

If I hover the pointer over a `[FBSDKProfile currentProfile]` instance, it doesn't display the `profileImage` property in the list of properties.

This is where it failed:[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you.

```
  -(void)getFacebookProfileInfos:(NSString*)token{

    FBSDKGraphRequest *requestMe = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields":@"id, name, picture.type(large),email"}];

   FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];

   [connection addRequest:requestMe completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
    {
       if(result)
       {
         APP_DELEGATE.socialEmail=result[@"email"];
         APP_DELEGATE.socialName= result[@"name"];
         APP_DELEGATE.socialImage= result[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"];
         APP_DELEGATE.socialAcessToken=token;


         HomeVC *obj = SB_IDENTIFIER(@"home");
         SB_PUSH(obj);
       }
       else
       {
         NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
       }
    }];
   [connection start];
   }
```

Comment: I see, could you explain the part of the code where you set the properties to `APP_DELEGATE`? How does that work?

Comment: That is nothing. I was passing values to AppDelegate. You can do whatever you want inside that if block

Comment: I don't think that is problem. The download is working, but trying to read the value often fails

Comment: I am also fetching profile pic from facebook and saving that pic in NSUserDefault for making it visible all the time on an imageView until I logout from facebook.